# Number of ways of winning a particular kind of game

Tags: combinatorics

There are $N$ cards numbered $1,\dots,n$. Let us call each number a denomination. These are distributed among two persons A and B. There can be more than one cards having same number. Socring is done as follows:

If $a_i > b_i$ then A scores $|a_i-b_i|$ where $a_i$ is the number of $i^{th}$ numbered cards with A and $b_i$ is the number of $i^{th}$ numbered cards with B for every denomination.

If $b_i > a_i$ then B scores $|a_i-b_i|$ where $a_i$ is the number of $i^{th}$ numbered cards with A and $b_i$ is the number of $i^{th}$ numbered cards with B for every denomination.

The final score of a player is sum scores of all denomination. The player with highest aggregate score wins. Find the number of ways player A can win.

Comment: How does scoring work? Do both parties get scored $|a_i - b_i|$? Or do they get that score for each of the $i$th card that they hold? E.g. if A has 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, and B has 1, 1, 2, what's the score? And what do you mean by "number of ways player A can win"? are the labels on the N cards known? If ties are unlikely, then A has about $2^{N-1}$ ways to win.

Comment: @CalvinLin edited the question. Apologize for mistake.

Comment: Do you mean that $N$ is even, and A and B each receive $N/2$ cards?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why do we have to put a constraint on N. I did not get you.

Comment: How are the cards distributed to A and B? Does each get the same number of cards? Are all $N$ cards distributed? If the answers to those questions are *yes*, you need the constraints that I suggested. If not, you need to explain more.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If there are $n_i$ $i^{th}$ numbered cards. Then A can get any number of cards from $n_i$ and the rest of the cards go with B. Same is repeated for all cards of all denomination. Then the score is calculated.

Comment: I think that I understand now what you’re doing. As a check, is this an equivalent game? You have $n$ positive integers $m_1,\dots,m_n$. A gets an $n$-tuple $\langle a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle$ of non-negative integers such that $a_k\le m_k$ for each $k$. B gets $\langle m_1-a_1,\dots,m_n-a_n\rangle=\langle b_1,\dots,b_n\rangle$. If $\sum_k(a_k-b_k)$ is positive, A wins; if it’s negative, B wins; and if it’s $0$, they tie.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, essentially this is what it boils down to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the game correctly,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-b_k)=\sum_{k=1}^n(2a_k-m_k)=2\sum_{k=1}^na_k-\sum_{k=1}^nm_k=2\sum_{k=1}^na_k-N\;,$$

where $m_k$ is the number of cards of the $k$-the denomination. Thus, A wins iff $$2\sum_{k=1}^na_k>N\;,$$

or $$\sum_{k=1}^na_k>\frac{N}2\;,$$

i.e., precisely when he has more than half of the cards. If $N$ is odd, exactly half of the subsets of the deck have more than $N/2$ cards, and A will win with probability $\frac12$. If $N$ is even, the $\binom{N}{N/2}$ subsets of cardinality $N/2$ result in ties, so A wins with

$$\frac12\left(2^N-\binom{N}{N/2}\right)$$

hands and hence with probability $$\frac12-\frac1{2^{N+1}}\binom{N}{N/2}\;.$$

Comment: That I figured out on my own. What's next. I mean that since the cards of same denomination are identical I can't use direct C(n,k) formula.

Comment: @Aman: See my addition. The point is that the identities of the cards don’t matter at all.

Comment: I still do not understand. Please bear with me. Here is what I do not understand. Let us have two denominations $1$ and $2$. Now let there be 5 cards, namely, $1, 1', 1'', 2, 2'$ ($'$ are included just to differentiate cards of same denomination for discussion purposes). If choose a combination $1, 1', 2, 2'$ and $1', 1'', 2, 2'$ for A then this is only a way of winning(counted 2 times, if I use normal C(n, k) formula without any constraints.) as A has 2 cards of denomination 1 and 2 cards of denomination 2.

Comment: @Aman: If A has at least $3$ of those $5$ cards, he wins, full stop. Are you interested in counting the number of distinct *permutations* of winning hands, and not just the number of winning hands?

Comment: I wanted to count the number of ways $A$ win. And I think that it should be equal to the number of distinct permutations only. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: @Aman: I don’t think so. I might be wrong, but I think that you’re trying to solve a harder problem than was intended.

Comment: Please explain the reason why you don't think so. I might get convinced..:)

Comment: @Aman: Two things. First, unless I’m missing some clever trick, your interpretation makes the problem unreasonably hard. Secondly, there’s nothing in the wording of the problem to indicate that the order of the cards held by A and B matters: the scoring depends only on the total numbers of each denomination held by each player.

Comment: Got it. Confused your answer with my previous thoughts. That's why messed it up. It was easy question, should have got it at first go.